# How to choose highlight language in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I want to know how to choose highlight language in Sublime text 2.

For Example, when I am typing some text, and I want to use C++ language highlight, then I want to change to Java language highlight.

Can this be done?

Please advise!

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 59):

Bottom right corner there's a dropdown where you can select what syntax to highlight

[image]

Also View->Syntax menu will do the same

Answer (score 20):

Use the command pallet (Ctrl+Shift+P) then type the syntax you desire "C++"

Then select the option you want "Set Syntax C++" press enter and you have changed the current syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have different highlight syntax schemes in the same file. If you want a C++ highlight and a Java highlight, you will need to have two different files.

That can be a pain when embedding code one language inside another, but for now what you ask for is not possible in SublimeText.

You could try posting a feature request, but my thoughts are that the only way to make that work properly would be for the text editor to parse the code that identifies which language is being embedded, and that will be a pain.

Otherwise, somebody might actually someday write a package that does that, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: Well, a simpler way would be to use some sort of markup in sublime. E.g. the user clicks on some bar to define sections, and then language highlight set on a per-section basis.

But yeah, not going to happen I don't hink.